# How can I change placeholder's color in ion-input?

Tags: input, ionic2

`<ion-input placeholder="please input" clearInput></ion-input>`

I want to change placeholder's color,and should not affect other pages.

Answer (score 13):

Give a class name for ion-input:

```
<ion-input class="text-input" placeholder="please input" clearInput></ion-input>
```

And add the following lines to your page's .scss file:

```
.text-input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: red;
}

.text-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}

.text-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though the answer by 99tharun works, current ionic (ionic-angular 3.8.0) offers the standard way of doing it via theme viariables.
See [ionic documentation for the input field page, SASS variables section](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/#sass-variables). Notice `$text-input-placeholder-color` variable.

Comment: The question was 'how to change the color without affecting other pages'. Editing the theme variable changes the color in the entire application.